# Resolving Recurrence Visibility in Microsoft Graph API: Seeking Endpoint Solutions for Daily Meeting Instances

Tags: rest, outlook

I am unable to see recurring meetings in the Graph API. Currently, it shows only one instance. For example, if there is a meeting that recurs daily, I should be able to see the meeting for all the days. However, it is only displaying the meeting on the created date. I have explored other methods, but if the parent meeting is not present in the fetched data, it won't show. How can I overcome this problem? Is there an endpoint or a solution available for this issue?

Currently using this endpoint(/calendar/events?top=30&$orderby=start/dateTime desc)